# How to get Google search results in a simpler format?

Tags: google-search, google-api, xml

Google search requires a JS enabled web browser to display the results. But I want a simple XML or JSON format, so my app can parse it.

I looked into Web Search API but it is deprecated. I looked into Custom Search API but it only returns results for Custom Search Engines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export Google search results](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/how-to-export-google-search-results)